# Upload img to 3rd party and get URL

Tags: javascript, image-uploading

I'm working on a resume site that allows you to link a URL, but not upload it. I don't really want to have to pay for storing images on my server for a resume project, so I was hoping to create a button or link that does this...

1. Upload an image to a 3rd party website/server, such as imgur
2. Get a link from the upload
3. Automatically insert the link into the form field I currently have for linking to images (I think I know how to do this part)

I'm not stuck on imgur, but it's one of the only sites I know that allows users to upload photos and get URLs easily without creating an account...Anyone have any suggestions? I feel like something like this must have come up before.

PS. I'm trying to advertise myself as an entry-level MEAN stack developer, so I'm trying to keep everything on the website inside of the JavaScript libraries if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What is exactly the question?

Comment: I would like to put a button/link on my website that will upload a photo from a computer (local file) onto a 3rd party site...like imgur. Then, return the link to my website and put it in an <input> on the same page. Is this possible? 

I do this manually all the time, I just go to imgur, upload the photo, copy the URL, then paste it to my friends on a different app. I just wanted to see if this could be automated.

Comment: yes it is possible, use imgur API

Comment: additionally take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2642570/1326271

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for including the link with the extra examples...apparently imgur API is down at the moment. One of the messages said it was "over capacity...."

Answer (score 0):

very easy to use as temporary hosting:

[img2url.site](http://img2url.site)

https://pypi.org/project/Img2UrlApi/

its not a good idea to store images there for longer time,
only as "buffor" to get an url.